# Save response variable from Request - GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I need to save the response variable from a request, areaRequest is a RequestContext this works but i can't save it and use it out of the scope

```
Long temp;
    areaRequest.countByCurrentInstitution().fire(new Receiver<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Long response) {
            temp = response;

        }           
    });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, after work a lot of time with GWT the solution that I found to this was create nested async calls.

```
areaRequest.countByCurrentInstitution().fire(new Receiver<Long>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Long response) {
// Here I pass the value from the first request
    anotherRequest.anotherFunction(response).fire(new Receiver<Long>(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Long new_response){ // Long again it could be anything it depends of your function
            doWhateverYouWant(new_response)
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: I think you are making it harder than needed.
Just look at the last answer Walen gave you.

Comment: That answer doesn't work. You can't save a variable from an async response. So the way to do this is just to call first the function that returns a variable needed for the second call. I'm not making harder, under my sight this is most simple solution

Answer (score 1):

You can't use outside non-final variables inside the Receiver.

A quick and dirty change just to avoid the scope problem would be:

```
final Long[] temp = {-1};
areaRequest.countByCurrentInstitution().fire(new Receiver<Long>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Long response) {
        temp[0] = response;
    }           
});
doSomethingWith(temp[0]);
```

But that is usually NOT what you want to do. Because (if) `countByCurrentInstitution()` is an asynchronous call, `temp[0]` would still be `-1` by the time you invoke `doSomethingWith()`, since the async method is still running in another thread.
You can make your main thread wait a bit by using a simple `Thread.sleep()` or (yikes!) a very long loop but, again, that's just a quick hack and prone to errors (what if the call takes longer than that?).

The best option is to ditch `Long temp` and just move your code inside the `onSuccess()` method:

```
areaRequest.countByCurrentInstitution().fire(new Receiver<Long>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Long response) {
        doSomethingWith(response);
    }           
});
```

Comment: this don't work, the temp variable after request scope is always -1, is there another way to get a value from the server ?

Comment: I already warned you about that: the first example is just a dirty way to avoid the scope problem. To actually use the value you need to move your logic inside the `onSuccess()` method like I show in the second example.

Comment: The reason why i need to do this is because in that function returns the modified value, but you can't use return inside onSuccess()

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comments make me think you don't understand the RPC mechanism of GWT or what an asynchronous call is, generally speaking. You may need to read a bit more about the subject.